# inserting new element in linked list with sorting C

Tags: c, string, sorting, linked-list, strcmp

I have a problem in inserting string in right position (insert sorting) in linked list.  When i add some positions in linked list and end program by typing ' 0 ', program show me only first position.
 Also i have doubts about "(strcmp(tmp->ch,new->ch)>0)" it is working as i'm thinking?(compare new element with current (i mean it should be '>' or '<')).
I will be really grateful for any advices ;) .There is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_L 30

typedef struct elem{
    char ch[MAX_L];
    struct elem *next;
    struct elem *prev;
}   list_elem;

void add_to_list (list_elem *first, char ch[MAX_L])
{
    list_elem *new=(list_elem*)malloc(sizeof(list_elem));

    strcpy(new->ch, ch);
    list_elem *tmp=first;
    do
    {
        if(tmp->next==NULL)
        {
            tmp->next=new;
            new->prev=tmp;
            new->next=NULL;
        }
        if (strcmp(tmp->ch,new->ch)>0) //guess here should be inserted new element
        {
            new->prev=tmp->prev;
            new->next=tmp;
            tmp->prev=new;
        }
        else
        tmp=tmp->next;

    }while (tmp->next!=NULL);

}


void print_list(list_elem *first)
{
    first=first->next;
    if(first->ch==NULL)
    printf("lista jest pusta!!\n");
    while(first->next!=NULL){
    printf("%s\n",first->ch);
    first=first->next;}
    printf("%s\n",first->ch);
}



int main()
{
    list_elem *first=(list_elem*)calloc(1,sizeof(list_elem));
    first->next=NULL;
    first->prev=NULL;

    char a;
    char ch[MAX_L];
    printf("write ' 0 ' to end program.\n");
    printf("write smth to add it to list: \n");
        while(ch[0]!='0'){
        scanf("%s",&ch);
        add_to_list(first,ch);}
    print_list(first);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint 1: What happens after you inserted in the middle of the linked list?.  Hint 2: Turn on all your compiler warnings.  If using gcc, be sure to set -Wall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's problems in the `add_to_list` loop :

```
do {
    if(tmp->next==NULL)
    {
        tmp->next=new;
        new->prev=tmp;
        new->next=NULL;
        break; // you must exit here, you don't want to go the "if" below...
    }
    if (strcmp(tmp->ch,new->ch)>0) 
    {
        if( tmp->prev != NULL ) 
        {
            tmp->prev->next = new; // link from previous to the new element 
        }
        new->prev=tmp->prev;
        new->next=tmp;
        tmp->prev=new;
        break; // you should exit here, work is done
    }
    else {
        tmp=tmp->next;
    }
} while (1); // try again
```

A problem also here:

```
scanf("%s",&ch); // should be scanf("%s",ch);
```

And for your question:

> Also i have doubts about "(strcmp(tmp->ch,new->ch)>0)" it is working
>   as i'm thinking?

If you're wrong you'll sort in the reverse order, so it'll be easy to fix.

Comment: thanks ! its working but its putting one position in incorrect order anyway again thanks for help! :D

Answer (score 2):

1. `list_elem *first=(list_elem*)calloc(1,sizeof(list_elem));`

   How do you know whether `calloc` succeeded or not?
   Check whether `first` is `NULL` or not and then only access `first->next`.

---

2. `while(ch[0]!='0')`

   Till this point `ch` array contains garbage. So how you can compare it with `ch[0]` with `'0'`?

---

3. `scanf("%s",&ch);`

   `%s` expects argument of `char *` type whereas type of `&ch` is `char (*)[30]`.

   Also you may want to avoid the accidental buffer overflow if user enters the string with length > `sizeof(ch)`. Specify maximum field width to remedy that.

---

4. `first=first->next;` in `print_list()`

   Here you just skipped the very first element.

---

5. `if(first->ch==NULL)`

   What you really want to do here? Most probably you want to check whether the string `first->ch` is empty or not. If yes then this is *not* the way to check that. Instead check `first->ch[0] == '\0'`

---

6. `while(ch[0]!='0')`

   For checking whether user entered `0` or other string, this is incorrect way. This will reject strings starting from `0` (e.g. "0bar")

   Correct way would be:

   `while((ch[0]!='0') || (strlen(ch) > 1))`

---

7. Break out of the loop once you inserted the `new` node in the list

   ```
   if (strcmp(tmp->ch,new->ch)>0) 
   {  
        new->prev=tmp->prev;
        new->next=tmp;
        tmp->prev=new;
   }
   ```

   Here after inserting the `new` node the `if` expression `strcmp(tmp->ch,new->ch)>0` will remain `true` in all subsequent loop iterations as we haven't change `tmp` and `new`. So this will lead to an infinite loop.

   The only exception to this if `tmp` is the last node.

   Solution:

   break out of the loop as soon as the `new` node is inserted into the list.
   Just write `break;` as the last statement in above `strcmp` `if`

Comment: 1. Well i don't know about this that it can be not "NULL" i thought calloc will do that first will be "NULL" 
2. Dunno it's working for me so i'm happy for that and didn't think about that  :f

Comment: 3. again don't know about that i just thought when something is introduced by keyboard i thought there should be &
5 . yea i want to check if its a empty but in that way it was working so again i was happy that it works :c
6. well i forget about that way thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when you're inserting before `tmp` you aren't setting `tmp->prev->next` to `new`

For clarity:

```
if (strcmp(tmp->ch,new->ch)>0) //guess here should be inserted new element
    {
        new->prev=tmp->prev;
        new->next=tmp;
        tmp->prev=new;
    }
```

Should be:

```
if (strcmp(tmp->ch,new->ch)>0) //guess here should be inserted new element
    {
        tmp->prev->next=new;
        new->prev=tmp->prev;
        new->next=tmp;
        tmp->prev=new;
    }
```

Side note: using `new` for a variable name is generally frowned upon as it isn't immediately recognizable as a variable since most programmers will have experience in Java/C#/C++ etc. where `new` is a keyword.

Side note #2: don't cast `malloc`. I did it until recently when I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) stack thread. It's a very good read.